# Can't resolve 'react/redux' in "..\containers\CarForm.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I get the following error when running npm start:

`./src/containers/CarForm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/redux' in 'C:\Users\james\Desktop\Chariot\chariot-client\src\containers'`

Similar questions on SO are resolved by running `npm install react-redux --save` (or similar variations).

I've tried deleting my package-lock.json then running npm install, as well as clearing my cache.

Here is my `package.json` code:

```
{
  "name": "chariot-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

And here's the file (CarForm.js) that has the issue:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react/redux';
import { updateCarFormData } from '../actions/carForm';
import { createCar } from '../actions/cars';

class CarForm extends Component {

    handleOnChange = event => { //rest of code
```

..

I used to have the error "Can't resolve 'react'" but not get the same for 'react-redux', so I'm guessing that I'm not importing it correctly (or something else very obvious).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have an error in the import statement, it will be `from 'react-redux'`, but in your case, it is `from 'react/redux'`, replace `/` with `-` and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the package name is `react-redux` so your import statement should be

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```